# Div not coming in order. How to fix?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Im making a little website using html css and js but theres a slight problem in the html part.

Code:

```js
window.onscroll = function() {
  changeOnScroll()
};

function changeOnScroll() {
  var winScroll = document.body.scrollTop || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
  var height = document.documentElement.scrollHeight - document.documentElement.clientHeight;
  var scrolled = (winScroll / height) * 100;
  document.getElementById("myBar").style.width = scrolled + "%";
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
  <title>Progress bar and nav bar</title>
  <style>
    h1 {
      background-color: cyan;
    }
    /* The navigation bar */
    
    .navbar {
      overflow: hidden;
      background-color: #333;
      position: fixed;
      top: 0;
      width: 100%;
    }
    
    .navbar a {
      float: left;
      display: block;
      color: #f2f2f2;
      text-align: center;
      padding: 14px 16px;
      text-decoration: none;
    }
    
    .navbar a:hover {
      background: #ddd;
      color: black;
    }
    
    .main {
      /* Avoiding overlay */
      margin-top: 80px;
    }
    
    .header {
      position: fixed;
      top: 0;
      z-index: 1;
      width: 100%;
      background-color: #f1f1f1;
    }
    /* The progress container */
    
    .progress-container {
      width: 100%;
      height: 8px;
      background: #ccc;
    }
    /* The progress bar */
    
    .progress-bar {
      height: 8px;
      background: #04AA6D;
      width: 0%;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>


  <div class="navbar">
    <a href="#home">Home</a>
    <a href="#news">Gallery</a>
    <a href="#contact">About</a>
  </div>

  </div>

  <div class="header">
    <div class="progress-container">
      <div class="progress-bar" id="myBar"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="main">
    <h1>A progress bar and a menu.</h1>
    <h1>A progress bar and a menu.</h1>
    <h1>A progress bar and a menu.</h1>
    <h1>A progress bar and a menu.</h1>
    <h1>A progress bar and a menu.</h1>
    <h1>A progress bar and a menu.</h1>
    <h1>A progress bar and a menu.</h1>
    <h1>A progress bar and a menu.</h1>
    <h1>A progress bar and a menu.</h1>
    <h1>A progress bar and a menu.</h1>
    <h1>A progress bar and a menu.</h1>
    <h1>A progress bar and a menu.</h1>
    <h1>A progress bar and a menu.</h1>
    <h1>A progress bar and a menu.</h1>
    <h1>A progress bar and a menu.</h1>
    <h1>A progress bar and a menu.</h1>
    <h1>A progress bar and a menu.</h1>
    <h1>A progress bar and a menu.</h1>
    <h1>A progress bar and a menu.</h1>
    <h1>A progress bar and a menu.</h1>

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Output:

[image]

But, as you see, the progress bar is above the nav bar in the output but in the code nav bar div is above. I want the nav bar to be above the progress bar. how to do that ?

I have changed the positions, but it does not work

thanks!

Comment: Did you try to use the CSS property z-index to control the z-level of the elements?

Comment: no, how to do that ?

Comment: Well you did with your `header` class. You can simply give your navbar a `z-index: 9999` to get it always to the top (if all the other elements are <9999 on the z-index).

Comment: to use z-index, simply use something like `z-index:999`. elements with higher z index will stack on top of the lower z index elemeent

Comment: What do you mean with `above`? Do you mean that the progress bar is at the top of the window, but you want that it appears below/after the navigation? Or do you actually mean that they are overlapping and you want to change the z ordering?

Comment: When Im using z index, the progress bar is not seen

Comment: Yes, I want it to appear below the navbar

Comment: You have an unnecessary `</div>` on line 7.

Comment: I removed it, still not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since both the `.header` and `.navbar` had the `position: fixed` and `top: 0px`, I just modified the top for your `.header` to 40px, that was able to fix your progress bar to some extent. I am not sure if this is the most correct way to proceed with it, but it does the job for the moment.

```js
window.onscroll = function() {
  changeOnScroll()
};

function changeOnScroll() {
  var winScroll = document.body.scrollTop || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
  var height = document.documentElement.scrollHeight - document.documentElement.clientHeight;
  var scrolled = (winScroll / height) * 100;
  document.getElementById("myBar").style.width = scrolled + "%";
}
```

```css
h1 {
  background-color: cyan;
}

/* The navigation bar */
.navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.navbar a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.navbar a:hover {
  background: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

.main {
  /* Avoiding overlay */
  margin-top: 80px;
}

.header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 40px;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}


/* The progress container */

.progress-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 8px;
  background: #ccc;
}


/* The progress bar */

.progress-bar {
  height: 8px;
  background: #04AA6D;
  width: 0%;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
  <a href="#home">Home</a>
  <a href="#news">Gallery</a>
  <a href="#contact">About</a>
</div>
<div class="header">
  <div class="progress-container">
    <div class="progress-bar" id="myBar"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="main">
  <h1>A progress bar and a menu.</h1>
  <h1>A progress bar and a menu.</h1>
  <h1>A progress bar and a menu.</h1>
  <h1>A progress bar and a menu.</h1>
  <h1>A progress bar and a menu.</h1>
  <h1>A progress bar and a menu.</h1>
  <h1>A progress bar and a menu.</h1>
  <h1>A progress bar and a menu.</h1>
  <h1>A progress bar and a menu.</h1>
  <h1>A progress bar and a menu.</h1>
  <h1>A progress bar and a menu.</h1>
  <h1>A progress bar and a menu.</h1>
  <h1>A progress bar and a menu.</h1>
  <h1>A progress bar and a menu.</h1>
  <h1>A progress bar and a menu.</h1>
  <h1>A progress bar and a menu.</h1>
  <h1>A progress bar and a menu.</h1>
  <h1>A progress bar and a menu.</h1>
  <h1>A progress bar and a menu.</h1>
  <h1>A progress bar and a menu.</h1>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Both your `.navbar` and `.header` have `position: fixed;` and `top: 0;` styles, so they're both going to appear at the top of the viewport, one atop the other.

You need to adjust the value of `top` in `.header` to a value that positions the progress bar where you want it.

Comment: this kind of worked, but theres a space in between

Comment: @John I'm happy to take another look if you can explain the result you're trying to achieve. Some sort of mock-up would help.